# list only rows that appeared thrice in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have tables called: `activities` and `deficiencies`.

`activities` table contains all activities registered by students. `deficiencies` table contains all deficiencies that the students might get due to the registered activity.

Here are the table structures with sample data:

## activities table

```
activityid  title
-------------------------------------------------------------
1           Student Retreat
2           Student Orientation
```

## deficiencies table

```
deficiencyid    activity_id     deficiency      status
-------------------------------------------------------------
1               1               NARRATION       CLEARED
2               1               PHOTO           CLEARED
3               1               REPORT          CLEARED
4               2               NARRATION       WAITING
5               2               PHOTO           CLEARED
6               2               REPORT          WAITING
```

For each activity entry, there will be three rows in the `deficiencies` table. **I want to be able to list each activity once if all the statuses of the items listed there are already `CLEARED`**. So if one or more is still `WAITING` - they don't get listed in the query.

I was attempting to do this using this query but I couldn't get any lucky:

```
SELECT * FROM deficiencies,activities WHERE status='CLEARED' AND activityid=activity_id AND COUNT(deficiencyid)=3 GROUP BY activity_id ORDER BY deficiencyid ASC
```

I was getting the following from MySQL:

```
Invalid use of group function
```

The output I was expecting is the first record in the `activities` table.

What could be the best solution using only one query without multiple `SELECT` in `SELECT` in another `SELECT` sub-queries? There will be thousands of records in the tables so I'm hoping that the most efficient query can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with a JOIN:

```
 SELECT A.activityid, A.title FROM activities A INNER JOIN deficiencies D 
    ON A.activityid = D.activityid WHERE D.status = 'CLEARED'
    GROUP BY A.activityID, A.title HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

This JOINs the activity and deficiencies tables, filters out the records other than CLEARED, groups by activity, and the filters out the groups that do not have exactly three records in them.

It requires that the data is guaranteed to be as you described it (always three deficiency records).  I wrote the GROUP BY to avoid using the MySQL extension allowing non-grouped, non-aggregated columns to be selected.  Also, I assume that there's also a studentid field involved which you left out for the sake of clarity, otherwise this whole system will support only a single student.

Comment: Hi Larry. Thanks for the quick response! What is the difference between using `INNER JOIN` and `SELECT * FROM activities, deficiencies`?

Comment: INNER JOIN is a more "modern" SQL syntax (technially, SQL-92 rather than SQL-89) but otherwise they mean the same thing.  However, in your original JOIN you need to specify the table name or alias before each column in WHERE activityid = activityid.  The newer syntax separates JOIN and filter logic, and is more consistent when using INNER and OUTER JOINs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! About the studentid field, yes you are correct. :)